# Parse exp:channel

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development, parse

Is there any way to parse tags exp:channel in a third party module.
In my custom module I need to call exp:channel, but need to get entry ids before final rendering of the module.
Can anyone know how to parse exp calls before rendering the module?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can't actually parse the tag using your custom module, you can pass parameters to the channel module and run it. Here's a code sample:

```
function your_module_method()
{
    // Set the parameters for the channel:entries tag
    $this->EE->TMPL->tagparams['entry_id'] = $entry_ids;
    $this->EE->TMPL->tagparams['dynamic'] = 'no';

    require_once(PATH_MOD.'channel/mod.channel.php');

    // Instantiate channel module
    $ch = new Channel(); 

    // return the entries
    return $ch->entries();
}
```

The result is that your module method will function exactly like a `exp:channel:entries` tag  with the parameters set as you configure them.

Comment: Thanks. Can u please help how to call this channel module in a custom module?

Comment: I got the answer. We can just include the file require_once(APPPATH.'modules/channel/mod.channel.php'); But I am getting nothing when calling $ch->entries(); Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that. You can use the PATH_MOD constant instead, as I've put in my edit above. Returning $ch->entries() itself won't output anything, it simply replicates the {exp:channel:entries} tag with your own allowing you to override and set the parameters. So you need  to place any necessary variables within your tag pair in the template to get data out. Feel free to update the question with your updated code and corresponding template and I'll take a look.